# Event for toolbars visibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

#### Installed products

- Visual Studio 2017 15.6.1

#### Description

Visual Studio extension that contains a toolbar with drop down combo still receives advised selection(IVsSelectionEvents) events after toolbar is hidden.

#### Steps to recreate

1. Use Drop Down Combo from https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Combo_Box sample
2. Use IVsMonitorSelection.AdviseSelectionEvents()
3. Hide the toolbar.

#### Current behavior

I could not find any event to be notified when toolbar is hidden/shown so could not stop receiving IVsSelectionEvents interfaces OnSelectionChanged event.

#### Expected behavior

Notified when toolbar is hidden or shown so Advise/UnadviseSelectionEvents() could be called.

So, i need an event that is triggered when toolbar is shown and hidden.

Comment: @susbcode, If you want to know whether it is shown or hidden, why not make it shown in default? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035795/show-a-visual-studio-extension-toolbar-by-default

Comment: @jack-zhai-msft, its already shown that's not problem. I need to know whenever its hidden by right clicking the VS toolbar and uncheck it and when its shown by checking it again.